# Django. Проверка авторизован ли пользователь для всего куска приложения

Tags: django, auth

Имею следующую структуру:

```
├── manage.py
├── Django_folder
    └── settings
└── my_awesome_app
    ├── models
    ├── urls
    └── views
```

Я хочу сделать так, что бы к приложению `my_awesome_app` имели доступ только некоторые авторизованные пользователи (например с username `customer_support` или `technical_support`)

С авторизацией пользователей разобрался, но застрял на проверке username

В flask есть отличная вещь как `before_request`, которая выполняется для всего blueprint. Но я не могу найти нечто подобное в Django.

Желательно сделать проверку на авторизацию в одном месте внутри приложения `my_awesome_app`, что бы в дальнейшем можно было легко расширять список пользователей имеющих доступ

Я прочитал о декораторе @login_required, но это не решает мою проблему с username

Comment: просто создайте группы с правами

Comment: ну и has_permission функционал (декораторы, cbv что удобнее)

Comment: в крайнем случае, есть прям оч оч надо блочить иначе - то смотрите в сторону `middleware`. Пишите свой  и подключаете после  AuthenticationMiddleware или как там его) найдете в общем, не ошибетесь. Но лучще обойтись стандартными средствами о которых писал ранее